# Chamada de método direto na instância

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, método

Me deparei com algo que parece não fazer sentido, quando tento fazer a chamada do método de um objeto direto em sua instância parece não funcionar.

```
class Pessoa{
        private $Nome;
        private $Idade;
        public function __construct($nome){
            $this->Nome = $nome;
        }
        public function getNome(){
            return $this->Nome;
        }
}

print new Pessoa("Vinicius")->getNome();
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Entretanto quando eu uso uma variável para referenciar o objeto a chamada funciona

```
$eu = new Pessoa("Vinicius");
print $eu->getNome();
```

Existe algum erro na sintaxe do primeiro exemplo?

Comment: Acredito que seja que quando você usa `$eu = new Pessoa("Vinicius");` você está fazendo uma referência e quando você usa simplesmente `new Pessoa("Vinicius")->getNome();` você tenta acessar direto o objeto e acredito que isso não é possível sem uma referência.

Comment: @Silvio segundo as respostas abaixo isso é uma particularidade do php pois não existe isso acessar um método apenas pela referencia do objeto.

Comment: Desculpe, falha no engano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**PHP >= 5.4**

A partir do PHP 5.4 você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
print (new Pessoa("Vinicius"))->getNome();
```

**PHP < 5.4**

Para as versões anteriores ao 5.4, é possível obter um resultado parecido declarando uma função global com o mesmo nome da classe, retornando uma nova instância dessa classe.

```
class Pessoa{
        private $Nome;
        private $Idade;
        public function __construct($nome){
            $this->Nome = $nome;
        }
        public function getNome(){
            return $this->Nome;
        }
}

function Pessoa($nome){
    return new Pessoa($nome);
}


print Pessoa("Vinicius")->getNome();
```

Embora o segundo método pareça ser absurdo, é exatamente isso que o Laravel faz a partir da versão 5 com seus [*helpers*](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php) para diminuir a verbosidade nas chamadas de instancias simples.

[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1402526/2099835)

Comment: A solução proposta no PHP 5.4 é bem elegante, mas usar uma função com o mesmo nome da classe me parece uma gambiarra sem tamanho :)

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti também concordo que é uma gambiarra sem tamanho... mas já que a linguagem permite... rs

Answer (score 2):

Isso não é possível em versões anteriores ao PHP 5.4

Infelizmente você precisa usar a segunda forma, porém em versões mais recentes bastaria adicionar parênteses em torno de sua instância:

```
print (new Pessoa("Vinicius"))->getNome();
```

Answer (score 2):

Essa funcionalidade, [Class member access on instantiation](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration54.new-features.php), está disponivel apenas na versão 5.4 ou superior do php. Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
echo (new Pessoa('Vinicius'))->getNome();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do construct você pode retornar a própria classe criando uma interface fluente.

Conforme:

```
return $this;
```

Comment: Qual a finalidade de retornar algo no construtor?